# Not able to ping NPM Registry url from WSL1 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Not able to ping npm registry url https://registry.npmjs.org/ from Ubuntu WSL1. Rest everything is pingable.

Here is the terminal output from WSL1 -

```
$ ping registry.npmjs.org
ping: registry.npmjs.org: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ ping 8.8.8.8 -c 3
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=38.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=38.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=38.7 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.044/38.496/38.752/0.358 ms

$ ping google.com -c 3
PING google.com (142.250.71.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s35-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.71.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=45.4 ms
64 bytes from maa03s35-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.71.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=55.3 ms
64 bytes from maa03s35-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.71.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=46.3 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 45.494/49.054/55.336/4.458 ms
```

This is how **/etc/resolv.conf** file looks like

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::1
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::2
```

Output of **dig registry.npmjs.org** command -

```
$ dig registry.npmjs.org 

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.15-Ubuntu <<>> registry.npmjs.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54664
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 12, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;registry.npmjs.org.            IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.23.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.24.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.25.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.26.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.27.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.16.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.17.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.18.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.19.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.20.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.21.35
registry.npmjs.org.     189     IN      A       104.16.22.35

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 23 16:51:32 IST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 444
```

Same ping works fine in CMD and Powershell.

Please let me know if my post needs any update. Thank You in advance.

Comment: What’s your “next hop” DNS server? Your router? Your ISP? Or something else like Google, Cloudflare, …? You can check in `/etc/resolv.conf` in WSL.

Comment: @DanielB, I have updated the post with /etc/resolv.conf file output.

Comment: What is the output of `dig registry.npmjs.org` from within WSL

Comment: @Malik, I have updated the post with the output of the command you gave.

Comment: If you’re still experiencing the problem, I suggest trying a different DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`, maybe Google DNS, Cloudflare DNS or something similar. Just not your ISP and not your router. WSL has some peculiar network behaviors that could upset your router.

Comment: @DanielB, can we use 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: That’s Google DNS, so yes.

Comment: @DanielB , How do we need to add the Google DNS /etc/resolv.conf file ??